# Latex source-code clarity and navigation

Tags: formatting, ide

How do you (personally) make latex source code more readable? Sometimes it can be hard to visually navigate if \section{} or \proposition{} doesn't pop out at you. The syntax highlighting in TexStudio is OK, but sections, theorems, aligns, etc. all look the same: Same size, color, font. I might have like 5 nested environments, which makes this a problem visually.

Do you just get used to scanning, or is there some better way? Is there a best practices for source code?

What I've been doing until now is using comment marks for clarity. But this can get tedious. E.g.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{proposition}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Let $A:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow 2^{\mathcal{H}}$ be a monotone, set-valued operator. $A$ is $\sigma$- strongly maximally monotone if and only if $J_{\gamma A}$ is $1+\gamma\sigma$-cocoercive.

\end{proposition}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: For environments, especially nested ones, consistent indentation goes a long way.

Comment: Indentation is a must. An outline view provided by your editor is also useful. For example, I wouldn't format that like that at all, if that is not too many 'that's ;).

Answer (score 3):

I think it is very personal and depends, also, on the kind of document you are typesetting.

At a minimum, your editor should preserve indentation and offer syntax highlighting. Ideally, it should be able to correctly indent for you (or, at least, correct indentation in simple cases which are the vast majority); support custom syntax highlighting; support code-folding (ideally customisable).

At a minimum, you should separate content from format by using semantic mark-up when ready-made macros exist to support this. Ideally, you should create custom macros to support customised semantic mark-up, reducing document clutter.

Here's a minimal example based on your code fragment with some commentary.

```
\documentclass{article}
% BEGIN preamble
% The preamble gets special comment lines which Kile recognises as a bit of code which can be folded or unfolded.
% If the document gets too cluttered, I'm probably not using semantic mark-up and need to add some code here or in a custom class or package to keep format distinct from content.
% END preamble
\begin{document}

Each sentence gets a new line to facilitate versioning.

Every sectional division gets a \verb|\label| followed by a \verb|% BEGIN <label>| and is ended by a \verb|% END <label>|.
Kile will make the result foldable, even though it is not an environment.

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
% BEGIN sec:section

\begin{proposition}
  Let $A:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow 2^{\mathcal{H}}$ be a monotone, set-valued operator.
  $A$ is $\sigma$- strongly maximally monotone if and only if $J_{\gamma A}$ is $1+\gamma\sigma$-cocoercive.
\end{proposition}

% END sec:section

\end{document}
```

[image: Kile]

Answer (score 0):

Your editor plays a crucial role in making things readable, but a judicious use of comments helps make the file more readable. I doubt there is one single, best way. Clearly, cfr's method works well. I have used the following method for some time, which works well for me --- but I tend to use Emacs in a terminal emulator (i.e., `emacs -nw`), so perhaps that means it wouldn't be as helpful in another editor. For example, the 'comment lines' all extend to the 70th character because Emacs will hard wrap lines (e.g., via `M-q`) at that point.

```
\documentclass[openany]{report}

% Fonts and Encoding ================================================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

% Language settings --------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[british]{babel}

% Page Layout ========================================================

% Page dimensions ----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}

% Headers / Footers --------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[compact, pagestyles]{titlesec}% loads titleps.sty

% commands about section-styline

% commands about headers and footers

% and so on....

\begin{document}

% Front matter =======================================================

\tableofcontents

% Main matter ========================================================
\chapter{Above All, Use Emacs}% ==============================

Emacs offers all the usual bells and whistles that help make writing
.tex documents easier.

\section{\ldots But If You Must}% ------------------------------------

Apparently other editors offer some measure of functionality. Make
sure yours helps you with syntax highlighting, and code indenting at a
bare minimum.

\section{Make Use of Comments}% --------------------------------------

I like to distinguish between comments that use an equal sign (viz,
\verb+===+) and comments that use a simple dash (i.e.,
\verb+---+). The former is indicates---in a very general sense---a
bigger `division' in the document compared to the latter. I find it
less jarring that a solid line of \verb+%%%+.

\end{document}
```

Note: the above is not meant to be any sort of comment about what packages to use and so on. It's more meant to show the hierarchy of 'comment lines': languages and fonts are connected,